# Opencart Featured Row Configuration?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, opencart, stylesheet

Morning Stackoverflow community,

I've search for the past three day's on this problem & still have not come up with a solution to this problem. The web address is vape-ashworths.co.uk and as you can see there are 4 Featured items, I would like the 5th to be placed at the end of the row. I've edited the ratio to 20% and even 5% and no matter how much room there is i can't seem to get the last box to float beside the rest. I would apreciate it someone knows the correct solution.

I have also tried the setting within opencart for example setting featured limit etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alreet Steve! Thought I'd answer this for you, seen as though it didn't really get answered... Just drop out the ".product-layout" class from the second div on the featured.tpl/latest.tpl.

The page doesn't have grid control like the category pages, so common.js injects a cheeky bit of java that doesn't work as columns/grids aren't defined.

.product-layout class is only used a tag for java so won't hurt it.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to show 5 product in one row then change array_slice limit in your featured.php  file

Go here

> > /catalog/controller/module/featured.php

find this

> > $products = array_slice($products, 0, 4);

change to

> > $products = array_slice($products, 0, 5);

Comment: When i do this i get ,

 Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '(int)' (int) (T_INT_CAST) in /homepages/42/d575305657/htdocs/catalog/controller/module/featured.php on line 25

Comment: are you find any <div class="clearfix"></div>  div under product for loop in this page  /catalog/controller/module/featured.php ?